# GCP - How to update api specification in API Gateway

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-api-gateway

I have created an API Gateway and created an API config as well associated with it which lists a set of APIs. Now I want to add/modify a set of APIs. How do I update the same API config of this gateway?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

I did it using gcloud CLI.

First create a new config using your updated open api spec file:

```
gcloud api-gateway api-configs create NEW_CONFIG_ID --api=MY_API --openapi-spec=openapi2-functions.yaml
```

Then update your api gateway with new config:

```
gcloud api-gateway gateways update MY-GATEWAY --api=MY-API --api-config=NEW_CONFIG_ID --location=YOUR_LOCATION
```

Comment: Thanks for your response. Yeah, I achieved this using the same approach a few days ago. I should have mentioned here. But I was really interested in was modifying the same config. Looks like that is not a possibility. What do you think?

Comment: I dont think this is possible, i read the command with the help flag:

gcloud api-gateway api-configs update --help

Output: 
DESCRIPTION
    Update an API Gateway API config.
    NOTE: Only the name and labels may be updated on an API config.

Comment: yeah, I think the same. Thanks.

Answer (score 5):

The GCP [documentation](https://cloud.google.com/sdk/gcloud/reference/api-gateway/api-configs/update) mentions you cannot update an existing API config, only its display name and labels, and you cannot [delete an existing API config](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69660363/can-not-delete-google-api-gateway-config-file) that is in use by a gateway; meaning you need to create a new API config altogether if your config file has changed.

A workaround I found for this was to:

1. Create **new** API config, point to gateway:

```
gcloud api-gateway api-configs create NEW_CONFIG_ID --api=MY_API --openapi-spec=openapi2-functions.yaml 
gcloud api-gateway gateways update MY-GATEWAY --api=MY-API --api-config=NEW_CONFIG_ID --location=YOUR_LOCATION
```

2. Delete **original** config:

```
gcloud api-gateway api-configs delete OLD_CONFIG_ID --api=MY_API
```

3. Redeploy **new** API config with name of **original** config, using your updated config file, point to gateway:

```
gcloud api-gateway api-configs create OLD_CONFIG_ID --api=MY_API --openapi-spec=openapi2-functions.yaml 
gcloud api-gateway gateways update MY-GATEWAY --api=MY-API --api-config=OLD_CONFIG_ID --location=YOUR_LOCATION
```

4. Delete **new** config:

```
gcloud api-gateway api-configs delete NEW_CONFIG_ID --api=MY_API
```

An awkward workaround but it allows for an automated redeployment of a similarly named API config file in a gateway.

Comment: How do you work around the prompt `Continue anyway (Y/n)?`?

Comment: Never mind: `echo "y" | gcloud api-gateway api-configs delete [...]` works like a charm.

Answer (score 3):

Referencing the [official documentation](https://cloud.google.com/sdk/gcloud/reference/api-gateway/api-configs/update), it states that:

> NOTE: Only the name and labels may be updated on an API config.

Therefore, you would need to [create a new API config](https://cloud.google.com/sdk/gcloud/reference/api-gateway/api-configs/create) if you want to add/modify a set of APIs.